# bash: echo the output of a curl command in pipe

Tags: bash

I try to echo the output of curl in a pipe:
I tried

```
curl -s --fail --compressed -u $CREDS -X GET URL | echo * | jq -S "." > file.txt

curl -s --fail --compressed -u $CREDS -X GET URL | echo | jq -S "." > file.txt

curl -s --fail --compressed -u $CREDS -X GET URL | xargs echo | jq -S "." > file.txt
```

But they all didn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Remove `| echo` part. Didn't work is not a problem description. Please include example input and example and expected output.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `echo` use `tee`.

```
curl -s --fail --compressed -u $CREDS -X GET URL | tee - | jq -S "." > file.txt
```

---

man page:

> NAME
>          tee - read from standard input and write to standard output and files
>
> SYNOPSIS
>          tee [OPTION]... [FILE]...
>
> DESCRIPTION
>          Copy standard input to each FILE, and also to standard output.
>
> ```
>    -a, --append
>           append to the given FILEs, do not overwrite
>
>    -i, --ignore-interrupts
>           ignore interrupt signals
>
>    If a FILE is -, copy again to standard output.
> ```

Comment: Thanks, but now I got: parse error: Invalid string: control characters from U+0000 through U+001F must be escaped at line 19, column 3
tee: -: I/O error

Comment: @mealesbia Unless `curl ... | jq -S "."` fails to raise the same error, that's an unrelated question.